# Possible error in CAN-Bus shield schematic?

Tags: can-bus

This is a part of SeeedStudio CAN-Bus shield schematic. The vertical green line on the left seems suspicious to me. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a mistake. It's related to this statement on their Wiki:

> When you use more than two CAN Bus Shield in one net, you should take the impedance into consideration. You should either cut P1 in the PCB with a knife, or just remove R3 on the PCB.

If you look closely at the pads of P1 you will see a small trace joining them together. That is the "rogue" green line you found. By cutting that trace you disconnect the termination resistor. You can then re-connect the termination resistor by soldering the pads together again.

Comment: Yes, that very remark is what drew my attention to the pad jumper. I assumed "P1" is what I will be cutting. Also on the PCB the part is labelled as "P1". Now you are telling me the part I will be cutting has no special symbol in the schematic and is merely described by a boring green line. :) That is... unexpected.